# How to optimize images in Google Presentation?

Tags: google-drive, google-slides

Google Presentations allows you to crop and re-size imported images into a presentation, but the changes aren't permanent.

Is it possible to make image changes permanent and therefore save filesize in a Google Presentation? If so, how?

(It would be great to do it straight from the app rather than cropping in an external application and re-uploading content.)

Comment: Files using Google formats have a file size of zero, so you don't have to worry about running out of space in Google Drive due to your Google presentations.  By the way, the service now is named Google Slides.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. My main concerns is probably less about Google Drive Quota used by presentations, but the time it takes to load/present, including all assets (mostly images) I guess. Just to make sure I understood your statement: "Files using Google formats have a file size of zero, so you don't have to worry about running out of space in Google Drive due to your Google presentations". Does that mean Google Slides are 'containers' mainly for text/links to images/etc. ? If they reference images on Google Drive, those images associated/used by Slides will still take up space, right ?

Comment: Yes, Slides becomes the 'container' of the inserted image. Inserting an image creates a copy of the original. Changes made to the original image will not affect the inserted one.

Comment: Regarding your concerns, please add them to your question. Also mention if your concerns are related to presenting from Slides, downloading your presentation or embeding it to webpages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, changes made to images inserted to files of the Google Docs Suite (Docs, Drawings, Sheets, Slides, ...) could be reset but those changes could not be made permanent for the inserted image. It's worth to say that Drawings could be web published as images that later could be inserted to other files.

**References**
[Crop and adjust images in a document or presentation - Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=4600160)
[Publish a document, spreadsheet, presentation, or drawing - Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, references and comments (+1)